# What word is missing?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: 4 ??? 1up : O ??? : ??? Snippet from my SE profile : ??? book]

What four letter word is the missing word in the picture above?

Comment: Is it the same word across all 4 lines, or 4 differnt words?

Comment: You must be a big fan of Life Mushroom.

Comment: @WeijunZhou  Too right.

Comment: @Phylyp It's one word to solve all 4.

Comment: Does the three **"?"** mean it's a three letters word?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No, it doesn't.   But thank you for giving me an idea how to patch this up.

Comment: @BrentHackers I was about to suggest you telling us the length of the word as a hint, but thought it is too soon for one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> **dear**.

Explanation:

> "For **dear** life".
>  Oh **dear**!
>  **Dear** me!
>  **Dear** diary...

Comment: And I thought about **dear** when I was writing my answer, gosh darn it...

Comment: Yep.  You got it.  +1

Comment: @Brent Hackers +1 life?

Answer (score 10):

I'm just starting here, so this may be wrong, but it's worth a shot:

> **My**

Explanation:

> 4(For) **my** Life 
>  O(H) **My**!
>  **My** Profile 
>  **My** Notebook (Diary?)

Comment: This is... a perfectly good fit...  the answer I'm looking for is not 'My' but I can totally see where you're coming from.  I could be awfully nit-picky and pedantic, but in reality it looks like I may have made this puzzle too broad (>1 perfectly viable answer) +1

Comment: My apologies.  I've added a specific word length to the puzzle in a poor attempt to patch up a broad question.  I say for all to hear that this answer by GustavoGabriel is invalidated only by my incompetence and is deserving of your up-vote.  ...Also; to anyone who may point out to Gus that his answer does not contain 4 letters, I wish upon you all the things that people often say they "wouldn't wish upon their worst enemy" (http://www.playbuzz.com/arielw/18-things-we-would-wish-upon-our-worst-enemies).

Comment: Thank you @BrentHackers, I'll try to solve it with your newest edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

> life

Explanation:

> (1) Life mushroom
>  
>  (2) Coca-life is sugar free
>  (3) SO life resume
>  (4) Diary contains parts of your life